# How to troubleshoot response when using Query inside a For statement

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm currently writing an API with a query that takes input as an array and then deletes it in turn via a for statement.

However, if it is not a normal request (ex) result.affectedRows === 0) the DB will generate an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

How can I solve this?

**API CODE**

```
exports.delete = (req, res, next) => {
  const arr = req.body.arr

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let sql = `DELETE FROM post WHERE postId = ?`;

    Post.query(sql, [arr[i]], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
        res.send('Delete failed');
        return;
      }
    });
  }
  res.send('Successfuly Delete');
};
```

Comment: What is the behaviour if 3/15 queries failed ? What answer would you like send ?

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused by your code sending multiple http responses, i.e. calling `res.send` more than once. This happens in your code because `return` is only breaking out of the callback function passed to `Post.query`, so the last `res.send` in the `exports.delete` function still gets called, causing the error.

You can restructure your code to something like this to avoid sending multiple responses:

```
function runQuery (sql, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Post.query(sql, [data], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
        reject('Delete failed');
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  })
}

exports.delete = (req, res, next) => {
  const arr = req.body.arr
  let sql = `DELETE FROM post WHERE postId = ?`;
  let deletes = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    deletes.push(runQuery(sql, arr[i]));
  }

  Promise.all(deletes).then(() => {
    res.send('Successfuly Delete');
  }).catch((err) => {
    if(err === 'Delete failed') {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  })
};
```